# Correct formulas for the mean and variance of negative binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, negative-binomial-distribution

According to [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/pascal-distribution) and [StatTrek](https://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/negative-binomial.aspx), a negative binomial distribution where:

$x$ number of trials, $x = \textrm{1, 2, ...}$

$r$ number of failures, $r = \textrm{1, 2, ... }x$

$k$ number of successes, $k = \textrm{0, 1, ... }(x-r)$

$p$ probability of success, $0<p<1$

The the mean and variance are calculated by:

$$\mathbf E[X_k] = \frac{k}{p}$$

$$\sigma_{X_k}^2 = \frac{k(1-p)}{p^2}$$

However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749221/expected-value-of-negative-binomial-distribution) say they are:

$$\mathbf E[X_k] = \frac{pr}{1-p}$$

$$\sigma_{X_k}^2 = \frac{pr}{(1-p)^2}$$

I am completely lost here.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative binomial distribution has many different parameterizations, because it arose multiple times in many different contexts. [Hilbe's *Negative Binomial Regression*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004X9YGNQ) gives a good overview in case you are interested.

---

I'll concentrate on tying the Wikipedia (W) and ScienceDirect (SD) articles together. The StatTrek one is a bit hard for me to parse.

In the present case, there are two sources of confusion:

- On the one hand, the W article defines the negbin as counting the number of *failures* until we have a certain number of successes, whereas the SD article defines it as the number of *trials* (so, failures *plus* successes).
- On the other hand, the SD article does not explicitly define what $p$ is. It turns out that if SD's $p$ is the probability of *failure*, whereas W's $p$ is the probability of *success*, everything falls into place.

Of course, we also have that W denotes the number of successes by $r$ and SD by $k$.

---

So, let's unify things. Here is our common nomenclature:

- $r$ is the number of successes (following W rather than SD)
- $p_W$ is the probability of success
- $p_{SD}$  is the probability of failure, so $p_{SD}=1-p_W$

Now, for our random variables: let

- $X_W$ denote the number of *failures* until we have $r$ successes
- $X_{SD}$ denote the number of *trials* until we have $r$ successes

So obviously, we have

$$ X_{SD} = X_W+r. $$

Now, do the formulas for the expectation match?

$$ \begin{align*}
 E X_{SD} 
 = & EX_W+r \quad\text{by additivity of the expectation} \\
 = & \frac{p_Wr}{1-p_W}+r \quad\text{from W} \\
 = & \frac{(1-p_{SD})r}{p_{SD}}+r \quad\text{because $p_W=1-p_{SD}$} \\
 = & \frac{r}{p_{SD}} \\
 = & E X_{SD} \quad\text{from SD.}
\end{align*}
$$

So the formulas the expectation match.

For the variance,
$$ \begin{align*}
 \sigma^2_{X_{SD}}
 = &  \sigma^2_{X_W} \quad\text{by additivity of the expectation} \\
 = & \frac{p_Wr}{(1-p_W)^2} \quad\text{from W} \\
 = & \frac{(1-p_{SD})r}{p_{SD}^2} \quad\text{because $p_W=1-p_{SD}$} \\
 = & \sigma^2_{X_{SD}} \quad\text{from SD.}
\end{align*}
$$

So the formulas for the variance also match.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!!!  Would you mind reviewing my question on NegBin CDF [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657786/is-my-formula-for-the-cdf-of-negative-binomial-distribution-right) too?